# Collection_Select Does Not Respond to Input_HTML: {Multiple: True}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form, collection-select

I am attempting to create a feature where users can add an existing record, `recipe`, to a collection of records, `menu`. I am using collection_select with a simple_form to allow users to select multiple records from a list however, the form is not responding to the `input_html: { multiple: true }` option, which should allow users to select multiple values. The form is as below, please let me know if any other code would be helpful for context.

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @menu, local: true do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title, :class => "form-component-header" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-field" %>

  <%= f.label :recipe_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select :recipe_ids, f.object.user.recipes, :id, :title, input_html: { multiple: true } %>

  <%= f.submit :class => "form_button" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.permit(....recipe_ids: [])`

You need to update the permitted parameters in your controller.  Now that you are sending multiple selections the parameter needs to be marked as expecting an array.